# SURF: How could we get the value of sigma from the keypoint radius

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, surf, opencv, python

In the SURF technique, and more precisely within the feature description stage, the authors have stated (if I understand correctly) that the description will be performed in a area of 20 times sigma. Sigma represents the scale on which the keypoint was detected.

Sigma = 0.4 x L where L = 2^Octave  x level+1. If we use the OpenCV implementation, the *DetectAndCompute* function computes, with the value of *Keypoint.size*, the radius of the circle surrounding the keypoint.

My question is : How could we get the value of sigma from the radius value  ?

Comment: Where did you get this sigma equation?

Answer (score 1):

According to [these lines](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp#L600-L605):

```cpp
KeyPoint& kp = (*keypoints)[k];
float size = kp.size;
Point2f center = kp.pt;
/* The sampling intervals and wavelet sized for selecting an orientation
 and building the keypoint descriptor are defined relative to 's' */
float s = size*1.2f/9.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

This value s = size*1.2f/9.0f is not montioned in the bay's article scale= L*0.4 or 
scale= L* 1.2/3 any one can explain me this part??